# Create a column of dictionaries from a column of lists that tells the values and a list that tells the keys

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

My dataframe has a column of lists but let's use a series (v) for simplicity. Each list includes the values of the dictionaries that I want to create.

```
v = pd.Series(data=([10, 20], [10,20,30], [50]), index=['a','b','c'])
```

All the dictionaries need to have the same keys (k).

```
k = [2022, 2023, 2024]
```

How do I create a column of dictionaries? The result would look like this series (d):

```
d = pd.Series(data=({2022:10, 2023:20, 2024:np.NaN},
               {2022:10, 2023:20, 2024:30},
               {2022:50, 2023:np.NaN, 2024:np.NaN}), index=['a','b','c'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

d = pd.Series(dict(zip_longest(k, x, fillvalue=np.nan)) for x in v)
```

output:

```
0     {2022: 10, 2023: 20, 2024: nan}
1      {2022: 10, 2023: 20, 2024: 30}
2    {2022: 50, 2023: nan, 2024: nan}
dtype: object
```

###### edit

keeping the index:

```
d = pd.Series([dict(zip_longest(k,x, fillvalue=np.nan)) for x in v], index=v.index)
```

within a DataFrame:

```
df['new_col'] = [dict(zip_longest(k, x, fillvalue=np.nan)) for x in df['col']]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! My v is actually a column from a dataframe with an index. I have updated the question to reflect the fact that there is an index. Your solution seems to drop the original index. How can I keep it in the result?

Comment: @ric then use `df['new_col'] = [dict(zip_longest(k, x, fillvalue=np.nan)) for x in df['col']]`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
d = \
pd.Series({key: {k1 : value[i] if i < len(value) else np.nan 
                 for i, k1 in enumerate(k)} 
           for key, value in v.items()})

#0     {2022: 10, 2023: 20, 2024: nan}
#1      {2022: 10, 2023: 20, 2024: 30}
#2    {2022: 50, 2023: nan, 2024: nan}
#dtype: object
```

Or with [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html)

```
v.apply(lambda l_values: {k1 : l_values[i] if i < len(l_values) else np.nan 
                          for i, k1 in enumerate(k)})
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `itertools.zip_longest` + `Series.apply`

```
from itertools import zip_longest 

res = v.apply(lambda vals: dict(zip_longest(k, vals, fillvalue=np.nan)))
```

Or without using `itertools`

```
def make_dict(vals, keys):
    d = dict.fromkeys(keys, np.nan)
    for key, val in zip(keys, vals):
        d[key] = val
    return d

res = v.apply(make_dict, keys=k)
```

Output:

```
>>> res

0     {2022: 10, 2023: 20, 2024: nan}
1      {2022: 10, 2023: 20, 2024: 30}
2    {2022: 50, 2023: nan, 2024: nan}
dtype: object
```

---

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

v = pd.Series(([10, 20], [10,20,30], [50]))
k = [2022, 2023, 2024]
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

```
import numpy as np
def create_dict(ls):
  dict_ls = {}
  for i,value in enumerate(k):
    try:
      dict_ls.update({value:ls[i]})
    except:
      dict_ls.update({value:np.nan})
  return dict_ls

d = v.apply(lambda x:create_dict(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an indirect way of doing it, not the best I suppose

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

v = pd.Series(([10, 20], [10,20,30], [50]))
k = [2022, 2023, 2024]
```

First I create a list of tuple with the right key-value pair

```
c = [[(k_, v__) for k_, v__ in zip(k, v_ + [np.NAN]*(len(k)-len(v_)))] for v_ in v]
```

Then I can convert it to list of dictionaries and pass it to `pd.Series`

```
def convert_to_col(col):
    d = {}
    for itm in col:
        d[itm[0]] = itm[1]
    return d

d = pd.Series([convert_to_col(c_) for c_ in c])
```

and you want this if I am not wrong

```
0     {2022: 10, 2023: 20, 2024: nan}
1      {2022: 10, 2023: 20, 2024: 30}
2    {2022: 50, 2023: nan, 2024: nan}
dtype: object
```